# hostname -f .com.com

Tags: networking, hostname, hosts, domain

I modified my `/etc/hostname` file and `/etc/hosts` like that:

```
hostname.com
```

and

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

1.1.1.1 hostname.com
```

after that I run `hostname hostname.com`

now when I run `hostname -f` the result is:

```
hostname.com.com
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to put your unqualified domain name (hostname) in `/etc/hostname` and your fully qualified domain name (hostname.com) as the first entry after 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`. I'm not sure what the 1.1.1.1 ip address is but I think this line should be removed.  This [askbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04) question might help clarify, although I'm still not certain how you've got those results.